# Was Latin widely spoken by European diplomats in the late 19th century?

Tags: 19th-century

If a diplomat from Germany were to attempt to speak Latin with foreign diplomats, would it be feasible that the other party would understand his Latin? Would Latin be commonly understood by diplomats of various European countries in the 19th century?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a hypothetical question. Factual answers to situations in alternative realities cannot be given.

Comment: This is a good question and should stay open. It's factual - did they speak Latin, or did they not?

Comment: [Documenting preliminary research will improve both the probability of an answer and the quality of the answer(s)](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/785/26786).  suggest that the question be revised to avoid the hypothetical, and explicitly address whether Wikipedia answers the question.

Comment: @NeMo "did they speak Latin, or did they not?" - If you pick a particular time when you can get a list of all of the active diplomats in Europe, then you can answer factually (assuming you can discover all of the languages they each spoke). Otherwise, it's a matter of educated guesswork. Is it feasible? Yes. Is it probable? That's trickier.

Comment: @MCW Just note that wikipedia is like asking a paranoic about The Men in Black.

Comment: @L'Hopital - LOL. OTOH, it is the site standard - to document prior research and to show why standard references (Wikipedia, Google) don't suffice to answer.

Comment: @MCW They are proved to have political bias.

Comment: @SteveBird, oh really, that is silly. We're not allowed to give probabilistic answers? How many questions in history can be answered with perfect certainty?

Comment: @L'Hopital  All sources have bias; this is history.   Far better to address the bias than the alternative.  Questions that don't address standard sources tend to be low quality, and detrimental to the site. The path to re-open and answer is to conform to site conventions, not to argue them in comments.   If you disagree  with site conventions, that should be addressed in meta, not in comments.

Comment: @MCW Everything have political bias, bet there is a diference between bias by equivocation, and bias by Agenda. And Wikipedia has been proven to have Political Bias of the second type.

Comment: @L'Hopital What makes you think that StackExchange doesn't have that? Or are you just looking for confirmation for some pet theory?

Comment: @NeMo I never said you couldn't give probabilistic answers, I simply said that you couldn't claim that they were 'factual' where you don't have solid data to back the answer up. If the answer is educated guesswork and you provide sufficient evidence to back up the guess, then I'm fine with that.

Comment: FWIW, I think the revised question is far better; I think including some minimal research would IMHO, make this a good candidate for re-open.

Comment: For people still doubting it's about alternative history or not, this question was brought upon [Worldbuilding Stack-Exchange](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/236950/80336). In there, the querent told us through comments they were only asking about the real-world part (ie, the question in title). I now let the experts here decide what to do with this question ;).

Comment: @Tortliena If they were only asking about the real-world part, then they should concentrate the body of the question on their previous research. Fact is, that despite the revolutionary/napoleonic wars in the early 19th century through out Europe did not effect the use of the french language per se. Previous research would have found that the [Hugenotten influence in Prussia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hugenotten_in_Berlin#Vorbildliche_Patrioten) was still very strong and that Bismarck himself considered them 'Exemplary Patriots'. Keep such questions to this reality and not made up ones.

Comment: @MarkJohnson I don't understand the possibility of Huguenot influence in Prussia of having relevance to my question.

Comment: @L'Hopital Do you know who the Huguenots were and which language they primaraly spoke among themselves until the early 20th century?

Comment: @MarkJohnson If they were Ex-French and Spoke French is irrelevant, because it is no about if Bismarck would ditch French of the diplomats about that, that is complete irrelevant. What is to know is that if they were to ditch French it would be possible to communicate with the other diplomats?, independently of is realistic that it would be to be chosen by Bismark. And if it were it an that way then this should be in Wordbuilding Stack Exchange.

Comment: @L'Hopital I will answer this if the question is reopened. The short answer is **no**, since in the few cases where the language used by diplomats is meantioned and not French it is stated that they used a language that they were proficient in. All of this would be to long for comments.

Answer (score 4):

> Was Latin widely spoken by European diplomats in the late 19th century?

In the few cases where the language used by diplomats is meantioned and not French it is stated that they used a language that they were proficient in.

I found no signs that Latin was used as a 'backup' language.

> From your original question [Was Latin widely spoken by European diplomats in the late 19th century? - Worldbuilding Stack Exchange](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/236950/was-latin-widely-spoken-by-european-diplomats-in-the-late-19th-century)
>
> Suppose that Imperial Germany hates to speak French, so they decide to use Latin to communicate when visiting foreign powers or speaking with the diplomats of another states.
>
> So it would if Bismark takes that decision, would the foreign diplomats understand/know Latin, so that they would be able to communicate with the German ones?

Bismarck was fluent in at least 4 languages, based on the only voice recording made in 1889 for a Thomas Edison representative. The spoken text of the 74 seconds recording was made spontaneously by Bismarck in [English, Latin, French and German](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otto_von_Bismarck#Familie_und_Lebensweise). The french text spoken was the first line of the Marseillaise.

- For further details: [2012-01-31: So klang Otto von Bismarck: Sensationelle Tonaufnahmen - DER SPIEGEL](https://www.spiegel.de/geschichte/sensationelle-tonaufnahmen-a-954424.html) (in German)

As the Prussian representative in St. Petersburg and Paris one can safely assume he was a fluent french speaker.

There is no hint that Bismarck was antagonistic towards the french language.

It is known that at the 1878 Congress of Berlin, which Bismarck hosted, the language used was french. The exception was the british PM Disraeli who didn't speak it well. This is a sign that each diplomat used the language they were more proficient in (using a translater when required).

This was the only conference that I could find (during the second half of the 19th century), where the topic of which language was used during discussions is meantioned.

**Conclusions**:

Any attempt by one person in replacing french with latin as the *Lingua Franca* is a highly unrealistic scenario, since it is known that diplomats decided for themselfs which language they used.

It is highly unlikely that Bismarck, known as a very pragmatic person, would have attempted such a replacement since it would have brought **no benefit to anyone** and probably would not have been adhered by anyone (thus serving no pratical purpose).

Even though your original question is tagged **alternate-worlds** (For questions about worlds other than Earth that are significantly different), it is a unrealistic scenario (both about the person and how diplomats interact with each other).

How diplomats interact with each other, as far as language usage is concerned, is probably true today as it was then.

Comment: Also, diplomats may well arrange for a translator even when they are competent in the language being listened to, as it provides additional time for construction of a response: a not insignificant benefit when every verbal nuance will be analyzed to the n'th level.

Answer (score 3):

**French was the "[Lingua Franca](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lingua_franca)" for diplomats in Europe from mid 16th century to First World War**, when English replaced French. French was used by diplomats in Spain, Italy, Germany, etc also in Sweden and Russia.

French replaced Italian. **Italian was the main cultural and also diplomatic language in Europe since the 1400'**. This is, since the Renaissance.

Latin was an academic language well into the 19th century, but latin was not used primarily by diplomats, altought **Latin is occasionally found in diplomatic correspondence**.

Comment: Whilst I don't doubt that this largely true, the question asks specifically about Latin but you make no mention of this language in your answer so I'm struggling to see how this answers the question.

Comment: In English-speaking countries Latin was considered part of a "classical education", and I'd imagine anyone with pretenses to being well-educated was familiar with it. However, Latin isn't really a spoken language. Or rather, when its spoken, we call it "Italian", "Spanish", or "French".

Comment: @T.E.D. There are modern spoken Latin communities, but they don't represent a living tradition. Mostly a bunch of over-enthusiastic serious sams. Latin was used to for new treatises, dissertations, and other serious works in the 19th century and earlier, so I think the question of whether it was *spoken*, too, is valid, given its widespread use in composition.

Comment: @T.E.D.: That's incorrect. Well into the 19th Century, liberal arts studies at European classical universities were ***taught*** exclusively in Latin. That was what the "grammar" in "*logic, rhetoric, grammar; arithmetic, geometry, astronomy and music*" referred; and likewise what the "*grammar*" in "grammar school" referred. If you were insufficiently fluent in Latin, you were simply ineligible to attend. Ergo, everyone with a B.A. was fluent in conversational Latin.

Comment: Latin was still used for diplomacy in the 17th century; Milton was Cromwell's [Latin Secretary](https://www.historytoday.com/archive/milton-appointed-latin-secretary). As regards the spoken word, it wouldn't have helped that we English had [our own idiosyncratic way of speaking Latin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traditional_English_pronunciation_of_Latin).